# How to create a WebSocket server using SuperWebSocket

Tags: c#, javascript, windows, sockets, websocket

I am creating an application which needs WebSocket Communication. All I need is a simple WebSocketServer with threading possibilities. I found that SuperWebSocket can satisfy my needs. But, my poor familiarity with C# makes trouble in understanding the code. Can anybody show me How to create a simple server Which should echo the message which is sent from the browser/WebPage. I will be very thankful to the person who shows some good direction||guide||code. I couldn't figure out the usage from their sample codes.

**EDIT:**
    This is the thing which I want to achieve.
     [image]

If anybody says an exact solution, I will adopt that one.

**EDIT:**
     "Robar" already gave the direct answer . This is jsut How I used it .

```
this.NewSessionConnected += new SessionEventHandler<WebSocketSession>(this.WebSocketServer_NewSessionConnected);

this.NewDataReceived += new SessionEventHandler<WebSocketSession, byte[]>(this.WebSocketServer_NewDataReceived);

this.NewMessageReceived += new SessionEventHandler<WebSocketSession, string>(this.WebSocketServer_NewMessageReceived);

this.SessionClosed += new SessionEventHandler<WebSocketSession, SuperSocket.SocketBase.CloseReason>(this.WebSocketServer_SessionClosed);
```

Comment: Just wanted to state that superwebsocket is already multithreads. A session is independent from another session.

Comment: Is there any way of using SSL -> tsl1.2 or tsl1.3 with SuperWebSocket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SuperWebSocket**

Tutorial for [Echo example](http://supersocket.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=First%20sample,%20EchoService&referringTitle=Documentation)

**Alchemy**

If you are open to other C# WebSocket server you could use [Alchemy](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets).
The server implementation is quite straight forward:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  var aServer = new WSServer(8100, IPAddress.Any) {
      DefaultOnReceive = new OnEventDelegate(OnReceive),
      DefaultOnSend = new OnEventDelegate(OnSend),
      DefaultOnConnect = new OnEventDelegate(OnConnect),
      DefaultOnConnected = new OnEventDelegate(OnConnected),
      DefaultOnDisconnect = new OnEventDelegate(OnDisconnect),
      TimeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
  };

  aServer.Start();
}

static void OnConnected(UserContext aContext) {
  Console.WriteLine("Client Connection From : " + aContext.ClientAddress.ToString());
  // TODO: send data back
}
```

As mentioned on their website, they have a simple [chat example](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets-Example).

Comment: Alchemy is really cool! unfortunally it lack some features right now. SuperWebSockets is probably a better option for now.

Comment: @Rushino: that's right. SuperWebSockets is currently the perfect solution for the projects in our company.

Comment: That nice to hear ! i just started using it and i think its really wonderful how it work and it work very well so far. So if you using it in your company that prove my point.

Comment: This project doesn't seem to be supported any more. There are several major issues and pull requests open for a year+.

Comment: @BryanAnderson yeah thats right, Alchemy seems to be unsupported. As of today I would recommend SignalR for WebSocket communication.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 8181);
        listener.Start();
        using (var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
        using (var stream = client.GetStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake");
            writer.WriteLine("Upgrade: WebSocket");
            writer.WriteLine("Connection: Upgrade");
            writer.WriteLine("WebSocket-Origin: http://localhost:8080");
            writer.WriteLine("WebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:8181/websession");
            writer.WriteLine("");
        }
        listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Err, that's an incomplete handshake with no later echo of client requests.  Do you have more code to post?

Comment: @tuoxie Your solution worked well. But,It didnt work when I removed that "using" and declared the "writer" as as object. Can I know Why?

Comment: @simonc Te remaining part is computing the sha1-base64 string and sending it to the client.

Comment: I found the answer for my comment. I have to use "writer.Flush()", if I drop the using.