# How to update HTML div from second/another page using javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have two aspx page. 
1) ActionPage.aspx
2) DispalyPage.aspx

- Inside the DispalyPage.aspx, I have one div `displayDiv`.
- Inside the ActionPage.aspx, I have one button `btnaction`.

If I click on `btnaction` (ActionPage.aspx), that time I want to update `displayDiv` (DispalyPage.aspx) text.

Any hint on this would be great help.
Thanks in advance.

--
Vina

Comment: :S Are the pages to be displayed side by side? If so, use ajax, if not, you should just bind the text of the div to a variable and change that.

Comment: ajax request sent from `ActionPage.aspx` and store result in session and on `DispalyPage.aspx` page continuously check if session exists than perform action

Comment: if the text is short,try using query strings.If the text is long use session as @Tushar Gupta said..

Answer (score 2):

the behaviour sounds like a chat behaviour. If all our clients/customers are running with modern browser you can do this with websockets. There is a .Net implementation for websockets available here (http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/). The advantage of websockets are that they are realtime. So you simply press a button on your ActionPage.aspx and send a message to your server and on your Displaypage.aspx got updated instantly.

You can take a look at this Stackoverflow question (server implementation): 
[How to create a WebSocket server using SuperWebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696594/how-to-create-a-websocket-server-using-superwebsocket)

And for the client you can use this tutorial:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm

Comment: No its not like chat behaviour. I have just given a simple scenario. Is there any jquery code to update HTML div from another page?